# Given a UTF-8 string, can I treat it as a string of bytes when searching for ASCII characters?

Tags: unicode

Since a string in many modern languages now are sequence of unicode character, it can span more than a single byte. But, If I only care about some ascii character, is it safe to treat string as sequences of byte (assuming the given string is a sequence of valid unicode characters)?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using rust. But my question is assuming that the given string is guaranteed to be valid UTF-8.

Comment: It depends on language. UTF-8 is compatible with C strings, so often program see it as a string, and the programmer encode the characters with UTF-8. But Unicode aware languages will treat code points (or sometime using two characters for codes above > 65535 [so using surrogates]).

Comment: In any case, when searching in unicode strings, you should care to normalize the string, or you could get surprises.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by treat a string as a sequence of bytes in the context of modern languages where strings are sequences of Unicode characters? I can't see how in VB4/5/6, Java, JavaScript, VBA, C#, VB, F#, …. In those a string is a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Comment: What I mean by treat a string a sequence of bytes is like doing `str[0]` on string type. What I mean by modern languages context is like Go, Rust, Elixir, Crystal etc. Go and Rust use UTF-8 if I am correct.

Comment: ["Some people think Go strings are always UTF-8, but they are not: only string literals are UTF-8. As we showed in the previous section, string values can contain arbitrary bytes;"](https://blog.golang.org/strings) That would be like Lua, C, C++, etc.

Comment: Depending on whether the UTF-8 string has been Unicode-normalized or not, you could either find your ASCII letter or not when there is an accented version of it in the UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

> [...] ASCII bytes do not occur when encoding non-ASCII code points into UTF-8 [...]

> Moreover, 7-bit bytes (bytes where the most significant bit is 0) never appear in a multi-byte sequence, and no valid multi-byte sequence decodes to an ASCII code-point. [...] Therefore, the 7-bit bytes in a UTF-8 stream represent all and only the ASCII characters in the stream. Thus, many [programs] will continue to work as intended by treating the UTF-8 byte stream as a sequence of single-byte characters, without decoding the multi-byte sequences.

From [utf8everywhere.org](https://utf8everywhere.org/):

> By design of this encoding, UTF-8 guarantees that an ASCII character value or a substring will never match a part of a multi-byte encoded character.

This is visualized nicely by this table from Wikipedia:

```
Number of bytes   Byte 1     Byte 2     Byte 3     Byte 4
1                 0xxxxxxx             
2                 110xxxxx   10xxxxxx        
3                 1110xxxx   10xxxxxx   10xxxxxx    
4                 11110xxx   10xxxxxx   10xxxxxx   10xxxxxx
```

All ASCII characters seen as a 8-bit byte have the most significant bit set to 0. But in multi-byte encoded characters, all bytes have the MSB set to 1.

---

Note that UTF8 is one encoding of Unicode. They are not the same! My answer talks about UTF8 encoded strings (which luckily is the most prominent encoding).

An additional thing to be aware of is Unicode normalization, combining characters and other characters that "kind of" contain an ASCII character. Take the Umlaut ä for example:

```
ä      0xC3A4    LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
ä      0x61CC88  LATIN SMALL LETTER A  +  COMBINING DIAERESIS
```

If you search for the ASCII character 'a', you will find it in the second line, but not in the first one, despite the lines logically containing the same "user perceived characters". You can tackle this at least partially by normalizing your strings beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful to drop the notion of a unicode character and rather talk about a *unicode codpoint* (for example U+0065: 'LATIN SMALL LETTER E') and different *encodings* (ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc). You are asking about properties of the UTF-8 encoding. In the case of UTF-8: code points below U+0080 have the same encoding as ASCII. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) has a nice table

```
Number      Bits for     First       Last        Byte 1    Byte 2
of bytes    code point   code point  code point   
1           7            U+0000      U+007F      0xxxxxxx
2           11           U+0080      U+07FF      110xxxxx  10xxxxxx
...
```

Talking about strings in languages is too broad in my opinion, because even if you language stores string values in some specified encoding you can still receive input in a different encoding. (Think of a Java program (which uses UTF-16 for the internal representation. You can still serialize a string as UTF-8 or get user input which is encoded in ASCII.)